# Using Jackson to deserialize into a Map

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON object with two attributes: "key" which is a string, and "value" which can be deserialized into a Java bean.

```
{ "key": "foo", "value": "bar" }
```

The question is, given a list of such objects, can I deserialize it into a Map?

```
[{"key": "foo1", "value": "bar1"}, {"key": "foo2", "value": "bar2"}] -> Map<String, String>
```

Currently using Jackson-databind 2.1

Comment: Please fully address your question. Where is the problem. One can't see what you're trying to do.

Comment: Basically, you want to convert a property list/XML arrangement of data into simpler form where the "key" and "value" terms are removed, such that you'd get `{"foo1" : "bar1", "foo2" : "bar2", ...}`.  This can be done with a simple loop through the outer array, but I have (in Objective-C) seen other "clever" (though not necessarily cleaner or more efficient) ways to do it.  Unless you're in it for the mental stimulation, I'd suggest the simple loop.  (In case it's not obvious, use Jackson or whatever to convert into a List of Maps, then iterate through the List to build a new Map.)

Answer (score 8):

You can easily convert above JSON to `List<Map<String, String>>`:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.CollectionType;

public class JacksonProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        CollectionType mapCollectionType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Map.class);
        List<Map<String, String>> result = mapper.readValue(json, mapCollectionType);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Above program prints:

```
[{key=foo1, value=bar1}, {key=foo2, value=bar2}]
```

Comment: Which is not what he wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Since your structure does not match, you have two basic options:

1. Use two-phase handling: use Jackson to bind into intermediate representation that does match (which could be `JsonNode` or `List<Map<String,Object>>`), and then do conversion to desired type with simple code
2. Write custom serializer and/or deserializer

Jackson does not support extensive structural transformations (there are some simple ones, like `@JsonUnwrapped`), so this kind of functionality is unlikely to be added to databind module. Although it could be added as an extension module, if these "smart Map" types of structures are commonly used (they seem to be, unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and was surprised Jackson wasn't able to natively handle it.  Solution I went with was to create a custom setter on the object I was trying to marshal into :

```
public class somePojo {
  private Map<String, String> mapStuff;

  ...

  public void SetMapStuff(List<Map<String, String> fromJackson){
    mapStuff= new HashMap<>();
    for (Map<String, String> pair : fromJackson) {
      put(pair.get("key"), pair.get("value"));
    }
  }
}
```

Jackson is smart enough to find that setter to and can happily pass it the List.