# Dynamically populating drop down using only xml and java class

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have a map inside a Java class:

```
public class fields {
  private Map<String, String> options = Collections.emptyMap();
}
```

Using Jpring, I'm populating the map statically now:

```
 <property name="options">
             <map>
               <entry key="UNITEDKINGDOM" value="UK/>
               <entry key="UNITEDSTATES" value="US"/>
               <entry key="UNITEDNATIONS" value="UN"/>
              </map>
</property>
```

Now, I need to populate the options map dynamically by storing these values in a enum Java class.

Can anyone please help me with binding the enum class to the xml?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that uses Jackson to [deserialize JSON data into a Map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20109694/1898397). Same can be done for XML using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml)

Comment: Thank You Tarun. But after deserializing the JSON data into the map, how will i make a reference to the map in the xml?